# I am trying to import data from my google sheet into my html form and I can't seem to get it to work

Tags: html, forms, import

This is the function in code.gs, it runs fine with no errors and returns what I think it should.

```
function getJobData2() {
ss.toast("Retrieving Data");
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var selectedRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
var valueCell = sheet.getRange("Z" + selectedRow).getValue();
var gotoSheet = ss.getSheetByName('2018 Data Log');

// Assuming the data you want to return is in columns A to CR (90 columns)
var startColumn = 1; // Assuming the data starts from column A
var numColumns = 90; // Adjust this based on your data

// Get the range for the specified number of columns
var rowDataRange = gotoSheet.getRange(valueCell, startColumn, 1, numColumns);

// Get values for the specified range
var rowData = rowDataRange.getValues()[0];

// Log the retrieved values
    console.log(rowData); // Check if rowData is an array
    console.log(rowData[1]); // Check the value of the second element
  ss.toast("Data Retrieved");
return rowData;
}
```

This is the code in the html form, forgive all the commented out items I was just trying to get it to work, it doesn't

```
<script>
function getJobData() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(rowData) {
    // Assuming the data is an array of values returned from the server
    // Modify the code below to update your form elements with the retrieved data
    //document.getElementById('today').value = data[0]; //A
    document.getElementById('Customer').value = rowData[1]; //B
    //document.getElementById('Customer').value = "testing"; //B
    //document.getElementById('Site').value = data[2]; //C
    //document.getElementById('PAinit').value = data[3]; //D
    //document.getElementById('JobNum').value = data[4]; //E
    //document.getElementById('Notes').value = data[5]; //F
    //document.getElementById('GeoRec').checked = data[6]; //G
    //document.getElementById('AscQuote').value = data[7]; //H
    //document.getElementById('Priority').value = data[8] //I
    //document.getElementById('DueDate').value = data[9]; //J
    //document.getElementById('HrsNd').value = data[10]; //K
    // place holder for hours available L 11
    // place holder for remaining hours M 12
    //document.getElementById('ProjInfo').value = data[13]; //N
    //document.getElementById('Process').value = data[14]; //O
    //document.getElementById('DwgNd').value = data[15]; //P
    //document.getElementById('FndNd').value = data[16]; //Q
    //document.getElementById('DwgDue').value = data[17]; //R
    //document.getElementById('BomDue').value = data[18]; //S
    //document.getElementById('BomRel').value = data[19]; //T
    // place holder for kml OWNER U 20
    //document.getElementById('PricingComplete').checked = data[30]; //AD
    //document.getElementById('TowerHt').value = data[58]; //BH
    //document.getElementById('LatDec').value = data[66]; //BP
    //document.getElementById('LonDec').value = data[67]; //BQ
    //document.getElementById('State').value = data[70]; //BT
    //document.getElementById('County').value = data[71]; //BU
    //document.getElementById('loadingType').value = data[86]; //CI
    //document.getElementById('extendable').value = data[87]; //CJ
    //document.getElementById('extTo').value = data[88]; //CK
    //document.getElementById('fallZone').checked = data[89]; //CL*/
    // ... continue updating other form elements ...

  }).getJobData2(); // Assuming getJobData is the server-side function to be called
}
```

I initiate this from a button:

```
<button style="background-color: orange;" id="getJob" onclick="getJobData()">Get Data</button>
```

it all runs but the values in the form just won't fill in, any ideas?

this line will fill in on the form if it is uncommented and the line just above it is commented out

```
document.getElementById('Customer').value = "testing"; //B
```

so I don't think it is an "id" issue
any help would be appreciated!